# MySQLi != not working on multiple AND/OR clauses

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, clause

So I have two rows in my Database - `user_one` and `user_two`, these rows are occupied by User ID's as numbers for a messaging system, I have also included a support ticket system within the same message feature but am having a few issues with this code snippet...

```
$sqlc="SELECT * FROM ap_conversations WHERE user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999' OR user_two = '$user_id' AND user_one != '999' OR user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999d' OR user_two = '$user_id' AND user_one != '999d'";
```

As you'll notice, the support tickets ID is `999`, and when it was kept to just checking that neither ID's were `999` this code worked perfectly. Although I also need it to check that neither `user_one` or `user_two` has ID's of `999` or `999d`. This current code returns `1`, when I know for a fact it should return `0` so I know something is defiantly going wrong and I think I may have it set up incorrectly. I have attempted to set it up like this in many different formats:

```
$sqlc="SELECT * FROM ap_conversations WHERE user_one = '$user_id' AND (user_two != '999' OR user_two != '999d') OR user_two = '$user_id' AND (user_one != '999' OR user_one != '999d')";
```

But still get the same results? Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here or how I can make this code perform better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   (user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999')
OR (user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999d')
```

...is a problem, it simplifies to `user_one = '$user_id'`, the `AND` conditions become irrelevant.

If you don't believe me, try a row where `user_one = user_id` and `user_two = '999'`.. It fails the first bracketed condition, but passes the second and is returned.

I assume you want:

```
SELECT * FROM ap_conversations 
 WHERE (user_one = :user_id AND user_two NOT IN ('999','999d')) 
    OR (user_two = :user_id AND user_one NOT IN ('999','999d'));
```

N.B. Passing in `'999'` or `'999d'` as the `$user_id` will still return the support tickets. I quite like this functionality but if this is not desired you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM ap_conversations 
 WHERE (user_one = :user_id OR user_two = :user_id) 
   AND user_one NOT IN ('999','999d')
   AND user_two NOT IN ('999','999d');
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! Thanks very much! I could tell it was ignoring something but just struggled to work out which part, it also seems to simplify it somewhat.

Comment: Does the `NOT IN` function have an opposite?

Comment: Yes, `IN`, but beware of NULL values for either operand/operator the function may not perform as expected.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use parenthesis to establish operator precedence:

```
$sqlc="SELECT * FROM ap_conversations 
WHERE (user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999') 
OR (user_two = '$user_id' AND user_one != '999') 
OR (user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999d') 
OR (user_two = '$user_id' AND user_one != '999d')";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this still doesn't seem to work for me though, the code still seems to return a result, even though the result includes `999d`.

Comment: Are you sure that `$userid` is populated and has the value you are expecting?

Comment: Yeah I've just performed `print_r` to see these results: `SELECT * FROM ap_conversations WHERE (user_one = '1' AND user_two != '999') OR (user_two = '1' AND user_one != '999') OR (user_one = '1' AND user_two != '999d') OR (user_two = '1' AND user_one != '999d')`

Comment: Try simplifying the query so you are sure it should work. Once you get it to work, start rebuilding it piece by piece confirming it works after each change.

Comment: See my answer, you have written the logical equivalent of `user_one = $user_id OR user_two = $user_id`

Comment: @Arth Please don't solicit your answer in another answer. Your comment to the OP should have been placed under their question. Unless you aimed your comment at John.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My comment, which, when undirected, notifies the answer provider (in this case John) and was directed as such. I could have been clearer, but it was an explanation of my downvote for what is not a solution to the original question and contains a rather large logical mistake. As I had explained this error in my answer it seemed mad to replicate it...  I would be remiss not to solicit my answer (which I believe is correct) and explain a logical failure in an answer (which doesn't answer the question) that seems to have been missed by at least 5 voters.

Comment: We should be looking at placeholders instead of variables in the sql string as part of a secure/stable prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add brackets in your query as below :

```
$sqlc="SELECT * FROM ap_conversations WHERE (user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999') OR (user_two = '$user_id' AND user_one != '999') OR (user_one = '$user_id' AND user_two != '999d') OR (user_two = '$user_id' AND user_one != '999d')";
```

Comment: We should be looking at placeholders instead of variables in the sql string as part of a secure/stable prepared statement.